# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No mapping for class java.awt.Toolkit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am getting below error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No mapping for class java.awt.Toolkit
    at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerXmlFile$MappingLocator.setMapping(TransformerXmlFile.java:96)
    at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:56)
    at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerMainImpl.transform(TransformerMainImpl.java:33)
    at com.mercury.bcel.TransformerMain.transform(TransformerMain.java:35)
    at com.mercury.javashared.transform.TransformersChain.transform(TransformersChain.java:35)
    at com.mercury.javashared.transform.CommunicationThread.processTransformRequest(CommunicationThread.java:76)
    at com.mercury.javashared.transform.CommunicationThread.run(CommunicationThread.java:42)
```

Comment: This exception is thrown by Robot class. What for or How are you using it??

Comment: Thank you for the repy... i am using existing hybrid frame which is already used..

Comment: can you post the relevent code?